# Syntax error with function input in function input

Tags: ocaml

I am writing a function that takes a function as input.
This function also takes a function as input.
I want to give labels to both those functions. I have tried:

```
let first (second: ((third: ('a -> 'b)) -> 'a )) : 'a =
```

but this gives me a syntax error "type expected" after the signature of third.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You have some oddly placed parentheses here, which doesn't make a whole lot of sense (hence why the compiler complains), but from your description I believe you want this:

```
let first (second: (third: 'a -> 'b) -> 'a) : 'a = ...
val first : ((third:'a -> 'b) -> 'a) -> 'a = <fun>
```

But note also that `second` here is still not a labeled argument, just the name that the argument will be bound to in the definition. To make it labeled, you need to prefix it with `~`:

```
let first ~(second: (third: 'a -> 'b) -> 'a) : 'a = ...
val first : second:((third:'a -> 'b) -> 'a) -> 'a = <fun>
```

The difference in notation is because `second` is not part of the type. You could also have written this as:

```
let first : (second:(third:'a -> 'b) -> 'a) -> 'a  = fun second -> ...
val first : (second:(third:'a -> 'b) -> 'a) -> 'a = <fun>
```

Comment: First is the function I am writing. I want to use second and third in my function. If both 'a and 'b are int I want to use "let new = third 1" and "let newer  = second thirdPrime"

Comment: You can't bind an argument that isn't in scope. The argument to `third` is something that will have to be provided when you call `second`, presumably in the definition of `first`.

Comment: How would I do that? Sorry but I'm rather new at this and OCaml is nothing like any other language I know.

Comment: I think a better question might be _why_ you would do this. The type doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me, but it is valid.